# Rename the partition column name in Athena

Tags: java, hive, hiveql, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm having an Athena table automatically created by Glue by crawling the parquet files in S3. It takes the folder name as partition and names this partition column as 'partition_0'.
Now, I would like to rename this partition as 'snapshot_date' and I'm able to do this in the Glue UI by using 'edit_schema' option. But on the other hand, when I try to do the same thing by using Java code, I'm unable to do it.
This is the query that I'm running through the java code to get this done.

`` Alter table test_java_crawler.pao_java_input_data change column `partition_0` `snapshot_date` string ``

And I'm getting the following error:

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Invalid column reference partition_0`

Is there a way to get this partition name modified programmatically using java? If yes, can you point me to the API that serves this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this feature using Glue client using this function:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glue/model/UpdateTableResult.html, which gives the option to update the partition key.